# How should I store 500 key-value pairs in a legacy database?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have a legacy table with 260 columns: 4 storing global values and 256 columns storing parameters. I need to extend the table to store 512 values.

The optimal solution would be to create a child table with only three columns (id, value, parent_id) and so store as many parameters as needed. However this will require a significant rewriting of the code and I am not sure about the performance.

Another solution is simply to extend the table (making it wider) to store twice as many values. This is a safer solution as I will need to implement minimal changes to my code. Moreover the new table will not be modified for the next 4 years (at lest), so it might make sense to stick with it.

Just to give a bit more information, my system does not have unit test (hence my reluctance to modify the code), does not use an ORM (therefore I will need to do many changes in the code writing and reading the DB) and the PM is concerned that the first solution might be slower than the existing one. I can expect to store 10000 rows in the table, so proposed child table will be about 5M rows.

Can anyone give my a proof that the proposed design is actually faster then the current design? Design consideration are not enough (the current system works...). Is there any other good (or bad) reason to move to the proposed design?

Comment: Do the child table idea. 500 values won't affect performance much. Consider caching them in a HashMap at start up if they don't change much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a key between database warehousing and snowflaking.

If this is a table where you are going to deal with a lot of reads vs a lot a writes you have different things to focus on.

Inserting an entry into the database after you break it into your "child table" will now take 512 inserts instead of 1. However, editing a single parameter will modify one small area and will not affect the other 511 areas.

Personally, I think that the 512 columns is a bit excessive, but I would consider whether there is some other relationship that can be turned into logical tables rather than the "anonymous table" of "whatever value I need goes here".

With all database things, the best thing you can do it *test it*. Only you know how the table is going to be most often used and writing a test to insert 1M rows and read 1M times is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will do some test whenever possible.